# If $A$ is the set of all $C^{\infty}$ functions with compact support, is it an ideal of $C(\Bbb R)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

> If $A$ is the set of all $C^{\infty}$ functions with compact support, is it an ideal of $C(\Bbb R)$?

I know it is not. But how to prove? Will this help me to conclude if I proceed by multiplying the bump function, which belongs to $A$, with the absolute value function in $C(\Bbb R)$?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The set of $C_c^{\infty}$ functions does not absorb multiplications: for example let $$\eta \in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$$ where $\eta$ is constantly one on $[-1,1]$. Now
$$|x| \cdot \eta  \not\in C^{\infty}$$ 
since it is not differentiable in 0.
So what your thought is perfectly correct and solves the problem.